# Custom Comparator - Java

Tags: sorting, java

I am having trouble understanding the Sorting using a Custom Comparator in Java.

`Queue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(arr.length, (a,b) -> a-b);`

gives me ascending order sort, while

`Queue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(arr.length, (a,b) -> b-a);`

gives me a descending order sort.

What I can not understand is how is this working? Is `b` the incoming element and `a` already in the array or vice versa? Also, how is the ascending or descending order obtained?

If `a-b > 0`, this means that `a>b`, so shouldn't `b` be infront of `a` in ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison-based sorts distinguish values by determining whether or not they are `<`, `=`, or `>`.

For example, `3 < 4`, `4 = 4`, `4 > 3`.

Java Comparators [use the convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) that

- `cmp(a, b) < 0` means `a < b`
- `cmp(a, b) = 0` means `a = b`
- `cmp(a, b) > 0` means `a > b`

Note that this means if `cmp(x, y) = x - y`, then you get the normal ordering for the integers. You can check yourself that `cmp(x, y) = -(x- y) = y - x` gives you the reverse ordering.

When sorting (or doing something else that moves generic elements around by their order, like a PriorityQueue), the algorithm will (repeatedly) consult the comparator to determine whether or not values it has been given are `<`, `=`, or `>`.